# Exception while trying to post data from PCL project

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, portable-class-library

I am trying to post data from **PCL** project to remote server. Below is my code:

```
public async Task<bool> SendToken(string deviceToken, string userId)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request;
            string url = "http://192.168.1.171:91/api/updatePushDeviceToken";
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = string.Format("userId={0};token={1}&deviceType={2}", userId, deviceToken, deviceType);
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            try
            {
                request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishRequest), request);    
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string m = e.Message;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void FinishRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;

            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);

            var responseString = readStream.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

While running above code, below exception was thrown:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (411)
>   Length Required.

PCL doesn't contain ContentLength property, hence I added Length as below but now I am getting exception as:

```
try
{
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = "0";
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

> System.ArgumentException: This header must be modified with the
>   appropiate property.   at
>   System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.CheckRestrictedHeader (System.String
>   headerName)

Comment: You do encode your data but you never actually add it to the request or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is missing of ContentLength property of your post parameters.

```
            var parameters = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(qstring);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = parameters.Length;

          //Send it
            var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(parameters, 0, parameters.Length);   
            reqStream.Close();

        //read it
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseHtml = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

And please use querystring format to post data, for example : "userId={0}&token={1}&..."

Comment: I am developing .Net PCL project, WebRequest class in PCL doesn't have ContentLength property